# What is the meaning of this error message I get when downloading documents?

Tags: computer-networks

Every so often I'll hop on my laptop, open google, and eventually try to download and open some document, only for the document to wind up looking like this:
[image]

What on earth does all this mean? What language is it, and why does it pop up instead of normally formatted English?

Also, if it isn't already obvious, I have zero technical experience with software and have no idea what sort of jargon I would use to even ask this question properly. Please keep in mind that I'm just a schlub who wants to know what this means.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake

Comment: Please follow the number one rule when asking for help on an error regardless of whether you are schlub or expert and whether you are on this site or another : describe [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What was the URL you were trying to download? How did you open the downloaded document?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is about how to open a document on the Internet, which is a software issue that belongs to [Superuser](https://superuser.com/), [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) or [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, that type of corrupt rendering is caused by trying to open a document in software it wasn't meant for. For instance, if you try to open a Word document (.doc) in Notepad, you'll often get something like that.

If you got this document from the internet, it's probably a pdf. Adobe Acrobat Reader is your best bet for reading this type of document. If your computer doesn't come preinstalled with it, you can download it for free from [here.](https://get.adobe.com/reader/)

If it isn't a pdf, you might need other software.

Comment: It's a file format based on zip archiving, which includes zip archives, but also xlsx and pptx files, for example. And JAR files. And lots more. The PK at the beginning is a good hint. PDF files start `%PDF`.

Comment: @rici Good spot - I had assumed the screenshot was cut off at the top so I didn't think to look for header bytes. That means it's not technically mojibake, since that term implies a character encoding mismatch, as opposed to bytes that were never meant to be interpreted as text at all.